# Inject beans when we create object with new operator

Tags: spring-mvc

I am creating spring bean using 'new' operator in one of the abstract class because in abstract class we can not inject spring beans using 'autowired'

Now when I create spring bean with new operator, beans are not injecting and those are null.

for eg.

```
public class A{
    @Autowired
    private B b;

}

public abstract class test{
    public void testmethod(){
        A a = new A();
    }
}
```

in the above scenario, b is null as I am creating A with new operator...

Answer (score 0):

You can inject beans in abstract classes, that is not problem as long a concrete class inherited from the abstract class is registered as a bean.